# Inset not even, even with object scaled in object mode

Tags: scale

I'm scaling my rectangle in object mode as suggested, and then insetting two faces in edit mode. Yet the inset is still uneven. I can only guess it's because I'm using decimals. I'm scaling thus:
x: 2.92
y: 6.2
z: 0.35

If it really isn't possible to inset this evenly, what are the alternatives to getting an accurate inset?

Comment: After scaling in object mode did you apply the scale?

Comment: could you please show some screenshots?

Comment: Are you using sub surf modifier?

Comment: Is there any reason you wish to keep the object scale?

Answer (score 1):

After scaling in object mode.

[image]

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and select scale

[image]

notice the scale resets to 1.000

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have not applied scale. You can do this by pressing alt A, then "apply scale". An alternative to this is just scaling the object in edit mode in the first place.